# footnotemark and footnotetext work wrong in endfloat package

Tags: longtable, endfloat

I want to use `endfloat` package to push all my fiugres and table at the end of the document like this (footnotes after end longtable.

[image: Table as i want]
[image: Table as i want part 2]

But when i submit my latex file online (Scholarone manuscript) i get this result

[image: First part]
[image: continue of the table]

Mydocument.tex

```
%any document class
    \usepackage[nomarkers,nolists ]{endfloat}
    \begin(document)

\begin{longtable}[!H]{lllllllll}
%my longtable here

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
\footnotetext[1]{Teacher $\backslash$ pupils ratio (per school).}
\footnotetext[2]{Teacher $\backslash$ pupils quality (per school)}
\footnotetext[3]{Class size ratio(per school).}
\footnotetext[4]{Class size quality(per school).}
\footnotetext[5]{teacher $\backslash$ pupils quality per district.}
\footnotetext[6]{Class size quality per district.}  
\end {longtable}

\end(document)
```

Comment: BTW, the optional arguments for longtable are l (left), r (right) and c (center), not !H.  See page 7 of the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should place `\footnotetext` after longtable, but then endfloat would not move the source to the end.  Instead you can create a wrapper environment for endfloat and put the longtable and \footnotetext both inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage[nomarkers,nolists ]{endfloat}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \newenvironment{wrapper}{}{}
    \DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{wrapper}{table}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapper}
\begin{longtable}[c]{lllllllll}
\endhead
\endfoot
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i
\end {longtable}
\footnotetext[1]{Teacher $\backslash$ pupils ratio (per school).}
\footnotetext[2]{Teacher $\backslash$ pupils quality (per school)}
\footnotetext[3]{Class size ratio(per school).}
\footnotetext[4]{Class size quality(per school).}
\footnotetext[5]{teacher $\backslash$ pupils quality per district.}
\footnotetext[6]{Class size quality per district.}  
\end{wrapper}

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thqnk youm but it's not working and still get the same preview (my footnote splti  my longtable into two parts)

Comment: I will post you the log file that generate online after upload my texfile

Comment: MyLog : https://pastebin.com/raw/pmN1b63E

Comment: Try deleting the .ttt file and running it again.  There is no way the footnotes should appear until after the longtable is done (at least for version).

Comment: i am just uploading my tex file online to a journal, and the system is compiling tex file to generate an article, and this happen online not in at desktop version

Comment: Did you move the \footnotetext calls outside the longtable?  OTOH, there is no way to know what exactly is going on with online submission.  Do you even know what document class they are using?

Comment: they use saje.cls file from latex sage public template

Comment: According to the manual, sage (or sagetex) isn't a document class.  It does however use python and shell escapes, neither of which I intend to implement.  OTOH, it doesn't really seem to do a whole lot, unless you intent to use python code in your document.